# Best way to access properties of my code behind class from the markup in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, scope

Let's say I have two files `default.aspx` and the associated `default.aspx.cs`.

default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myObject = new MyObject();
}
```

Is there a way that in the `default.aspx` I could do something like:

```
<%= myObject.SomePropertyOfThisObject%>
```

... or something similar, without having to use databinders or something complicated like this? And if there's no way around binding the data, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: defining an object in my .cs and using it in my .aspx

Comment: That's kind of backwards for webforms.  Get out of the habit of putting that kind of logic in your apsx code. Add a label or literal control instead.

Comment: @Joel: is it really better practice to do so? Sometime it just makes my code much more complicated and messier (adding a litteral, and updating it when I could just access the object)...

Comment: Think in terms of the HTML you're trying to generate, then decide. But consider that a control can later be styled. It's not just a text string, splat, right there.

Comment: In that case it would only be a text string (an id to be specific) like: "The latest id was #ABC15". This is why I'm looking for simpler ways to do it. I'm used to ruby on rails where you just change the scope of the variable and you can go <%=@my_var.property%> and it works fine, hence my question

Comment: Controls can also be cached individually, so if there's a lot of work into generating that control you can save it for future views.

Comment: Ok, then it will work; it just could be more efficient. For what you're doing, I think it would be better to set the label property to String.Format("The latest id was #{0}", _myObject.Awesome);

Comment: @joel The caching detail is interesting as well. It doesn't really apply to this page since it's really simple, but it's something I'll keep in mind.

Comment: @john what is the advantage of using the string.format? Resharper keeps on telling me to do this so I am, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can, but you'll have to do it a bit differently. In your default.aspx.cs, add a member:

```
protected MyObject _myObject;
```

Then, in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         _myObject = new MyObject();
}
```

Then, in default.aspx, you can do:

```
<%= _myObject.SomePropertyOfThisObject %>
```

Of course, this assumes that class MyObject has a property named Awesome. You didn't mean the System.Object class, did you, since it doesn't have a property named Awesome.

---

Since your question was asking about the *best* way, I'll go further. The way I showed is not the best. The best is more often to use a data binding expression. If you don't like those, then you can set things in the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         _myObject = new MyObject();
        //
        _myLabel.Text = _myObject.SomePropertyOfThisObject;
}
```

Assuming:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="_myLabel" />
```

Answer (score 7):

The <%= ... %> is ASPX short-hand for `Response.Write( .... )`.

If you change myObject to be strongly types (rather than just types as Object) you can certain use the line:

```
<%= myObject.Awesome %>
```

to emit a value.

Be aware, however, that the <%= syntax has limitations - specifically:

- it cannot be used within HTML attribute as a value
- it cannot emit server-side elements
- it cannot be used within ASP UpdatePanels - you will get a exception when you perform a partial postback

You are probably better off creating a Label control on you page, and programmatically setting the `Text` property to the value. This also gives you more control over how value-to-string conversions are performed. And will work correctly with update panel controls.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it have to be public to be accessible in that scope?

..

```
public var myObject = null;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myObject = new Object();
}
```

Comment: protected is sufficient (same requirements as Page_Load has)

Answer (score 1):

You can do any coding that you'd like to do directly in the ASPX file, rather than using codebehind.  So, to accomplish what I think you want to do, you would have...

```
<some html>

<% var MyObject = new MyObject();
   Response.Write(myObj.Awesome()); %>

<some html>
```

However, this is really not recommended. Codebehind is the suggested "best practice" way of doing things, because this separates your code from your markup, which is fundamental in any good architecture.  I would recommend using something like what John Saunders posted in order to avoid databinding, but you should really consider manipulating your controls in the codebehind using the lifecycle events rather than outputting object properties directly to your HTML.  For example, if you were trying to output some text, then do something like

```
var literal = new LiteralControl(myObject.Awesome());
myPanel.Controls.Add(literal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variable as protected in code behind (.cs) and then call that on aspx page to retrieve all data.

e.g.

```
protected IEnumerable<Class> _mydata;

internal void MyDefaultData()
{
mydata = doallthework;
}
```

on aspx page you can do like following

`<%=_mydata.FirstOrDefault().FirstName%>`

Make sure method is called on load.