# Asp.net: how to compare DataBinder.Eval with a member variable?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do this in a repeater:

```
<%# Iif((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") == SelectedJobDefId, "blue", "red")%>
```

Problem is that the member property only evaluates if this syntax is used:

```
<%= SelectedJobDefId %>
```

DataBinder.Eval() only works if the hash symbol is used.

As a test, I tried this:

```
  <%= SelectedJobDefId %>
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") + " " + SelectedJobDefId %>
```

The first SelectedJobDefId stays correct as I switch rows (LinkButton event). 
The DataBinder part is correct for each row. 
The 2nd output of SelectedJobDefId is always "1".

How can I compare these two values?

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestion by Jeremy, I made the td a server tag and tried to do the logic in OnItemDataBound like this:

```
protected void Repeater2_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;

        int id = (int)drv.Row.ItemArray[0];

        HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("failtd");

        if (id == this.SelectedJobDefId){td.BgColor = "green";}
    }
```

When I step through the debugger, the OnItemDataBound event is happening **before** the LinkButton event that updates the SelectedJobDefId property which explains the default value of 1.

Is there a way to switch the order of events? I may just be taking the wrong approach.

Comment: You are saying that `SelectedJobDefId` should be changing value for each row of the repeater, but it is *not* doing so when using the `<%# %>` operation?

Comment: As an aside, you could keep your aspx clean of logic and perform your comparison in the repeater's `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound` (depending on your situation) in the codebehind.

Comment: GuthMD: yes, it is stuck with a value of 1 if used with <%# %>

Comment: Jeremy: The problem is that I want to do this to switch the class or style tag of the cells of the selected row. Trying to think of a way to use ItemDataBound... Maybe make the table a server tag?

Comment: A server control would be great in my opinion if you can do it.  Then, in your ItemDataBound, you can access that control via the RepeaterItemEventArgs by calling myControl = e.Item.FindControl("MyControl") and then doing something like myControl.Attributes.Add("class", whateverclass), though there are probably better ways of doing it.  But, if you must, you could maybe  add a method in the code behind that you can call in your aspx where you pass in the id of that row: <% =this.GetClassForRowID(Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")) %> and perform your logic in the codebehind.

Comment: I just tried the FindControl (updated in question above) and also tried a function originally but it still evaluates the same. I think I may need to find another way to set the SelectedJobDefId so that it trumps everything else.

Comment: Although I don't think it answers your question, but these links may help you in your quest: [Best way to access properties of my codebehind class from the markup in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089239/best-way-to-access-properties-of-my-codebehind-class-from-the-markup-in-asp-net) and [get property from code behind into aspx page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924309/get-property-from-code-behind-into-aspx-page).  Apparently there are some limitations to what you can/can't do with properties with regard to its uses in the aspx.

Comment: I have used the hidden field method for js in the past and it may still be cleaner than dealing with the page lifecycle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting this out there as an option, though obviously not most efficient approach.

You could explicitly rebind the `Repeater` in the `LinkButton` click handler, after `SelectedJobDefId` has been updated. In this way, you should be able to keep all the aspx markup you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the event order issue by using the NamingContainer property in the LinkButton Click() event like this:

```
RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;      
HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("SelectTd");
td.BgColor = "purple";
```

To make this work, I made the target td runat="server" and named it "SelectTd". This is a bit unpleasant so I might just do it all in jQuery via hidden field to store the selected item.