# Accessing c# public property in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there any way to access the C# public properties in javascript?

For e.g. if there is following property in C#  code:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Could this property be accessed in javascript file?

Comment: are you trying to access it in aspx page ?If so see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089271/961113

Comment: Nope, not from JS directly. You would have to print the value of the property server-side in the ASPX, by means of `var javaScriptVariable = '<%= object.PropertyValue %>';  or something like that/

Comment: @Habib: I was not trying to access it in aspx page.

Comment: @JasonEvans: Thanks. If there is no other way, I would access it as you said in aspx page and then use that javascript variable in my .js file

Comment: Habib and Jason: Thanks for your resposne. 
As you both mentioned, I would use this way to access properties as I think this is one of the best ways we could do it.

Comment: @MrudangVora, all you need is you want to set the variable in a `window or global context`, so it can be accessible in a page or any js files referred in the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there are several ways

```
<script>
var prop = <%=MyProperty %>;
</script>
```

using hidden fields

html:

```
<input id="hiddenF" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

In .cs behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hiddenF.Value = MyProperty;
}
```

then getting the value via getElementById().Value

using ASP.NET MVC razor engine passing a model

```
<script>
var prop = @Model.MyProperty;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could refer any `public/protected` property value in your .aspx page with the help of [`inline syntax`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

**C#**

```
public string MyProperty{get;set;}
```

**.aspx**

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var propValue= <%= MyProperty%>; // available in window/global context
    //var propValue= '<%= MyPublicMethod("parameter")%>'; 
 </script>
```

**JS**

```
function getMyValue(){
   return propValue; // since it is written as part of page HTML, you can get it
}
```

some more reference for [INLINE Syntax in ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

no, but you can put the value into hidden field and access it from js.

or you can make server method and call it from JS.

Answer (score 0):

That variable doesn't exist in JavaScript because it is running on a different machine than the C# code. C# is running on the server and JavaScript is running on the client's browser.

Have your page write the property out either to a dynamically generated javascript var or to an HTML hidden field.