# ASP.Net User Control data binding error - property does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am going through a great book learning C# 5.0 and ASP.Net and came across data binding with controls. I have gone through the necessary steps to bind the data but I am receiving a confusing error message as the code below states.

```
Show.cs //Class for the show properties

namespace BindingExample
{
   public class Show 
   {
      public int ID {get; set;}
      public String ShowName {get; set;}
   }
}

LabelText.aspx.cs //user control code behind

namespace BindingExample
{
  public partial class Label LabelText: System.Web.UI.Page
  {
     protected void load_page(object sender, Event args)
     {
        Show show = new Show
        {
           ID = 1,
           ShowName = "C# is the Best"
        };

       //binding
       Page.Binding();
     }
   }

LabelText.aspx //user control markup where the problem occurs.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LabelText.aspx.cs" Inherits="BindingExample1.LabelText" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# show.ShowName%>"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where the problem occurs, intellisense is telling me that show.ShowName is not in the current context, I don't know why as first it is exactly what the book presented and also why it would not be since Show.cs class is in the same folder? Any help solving this will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as Intellisense indicates, you can't access `show`. You need to have a field defined as a part of the `LabelText` class.

(BTW, something is wrong with your class name - is it `LabelText` or `Label`? I'll go with `LabelText` since that's the name you have on the `Inherits` attribute).

So this is what you need:

```
namespace BindingExample
{
    public partial class LabelText: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected Show _show;
        protected void load_page(object sender, Event args)
        {
            _show = new Show
            {
                ID = 1,
                ShowName = "C# is the Best"
            };

            Page.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089271/3002584) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try making object of `Show` as public

```
namespace BindingExample
{
    public partial class LabelText: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Show _show; //this will allow this object to be used in aspx page
        protected void load_page(object sender, Event args)
        {
            _show = new Show
            {
                ID = 1,
                ShowName = "C# is the Best"
            };

            Page.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```